# WAMP 3 new installation tried everything

Tags: wamp, wampserver

Today I decided to reinstall WAMP on Windows 10.

What a mistake it was, after the new installation WAMP icon stays Orange.

I searched google for hours tried, everything I could, nothing helps, the icon stays Orange.

I checked the mySql error log and I get this:

```
2016-08-29T17:43:19.636578Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2016-08-29T17:43:22.277335Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
wampmysqld64: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2016-08-29T17:43:22.449217Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2016-08-29T17:43:22.449217Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 148b018e-6e10-11e6-aca6-a45d36c709dc.
2016-08-29T17:43:22.511719Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2016-08-29T17:43:22.527346Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2016-08-29T17:43:22.527346Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2016-08-29T17:43:22.527346Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Here is what I did:

I unistalled the old Wamp.

I change the wamp directory's name to: wampOld

I checked my services there were no mysql or apache on them

I installed all the VC packages needed (As administrator):

[image: VC Packages]

I checked IIS on windows, looks ok to me:
Web Management Tools and everything under it is unticked.

I installed WAMP (As administrator)(wampserver3.0.4_x64_apache2.4.18_mysql5.7.11_php5.6.19-7.0.4)

I tested port 80:

```
    ***** Test which uses port 80 *****
    ===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====
    Test for TCP
    Your port 80 is used by a processus with PID = 4180
    The processus of PID 4180 is 'httpd.exe' Session: Services
    The service of PID 4180 for 'httpd.exe' is 'wampapache64'
    This service is from Wampserver - It is correct

    Test for TCPv6
    Your port 80 is used by a processus with PID = 4180
    The processus of PID 4180 is 'httpd.exe' Session: Services
    The service of PID 4180 for 'httpd.exe' is 'wampapache64'
    This service is from Wampserver - It is correct

    ===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====

    Your port 80 is actually used by :

    Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/5.6.19
```

**The Apache error log:**

```
[Mon Aug 29 19:43:18.777165 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 4180:tid 496] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Aug 29 19:43:18.839665 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4180:tid 496] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/5.6.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Aug 29 19:43:18.839665 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4180:tid 496] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 11:13:29
[Mon Aug 29 19:43:18.839665 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4180:tid 496] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.18\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.18'
[Mon Aug 29 19:43:18.870917 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4180:tid 496] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6408
[Mon Aug 29 19:43:19.480326 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 6408:tid 432] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Aug 29 19:43:19.558450 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6408:tid 432] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

**The Apache access log:**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2016:19:43:51 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5145
```

After installation my services look like this:
[image: Services]

My hosts file has these 2 entries in it:
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost

Nada, WAMP stays Orange.

Uninstalled, and installed version 32 instead. Still Orange, got this in mysql.log:

```
2016-08-29T20:00:38.680630Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2016-08-29T20:00:42.132996Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
wampmysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2016-08-29T20:00:42.566098Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2016-08-29T20:00:42.590113Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 440b9e23-6e23-11e6-ba24-a45d36c709dc.
2016-08-29T20:00:42.703794Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2016-08-29T20:00:43.016750Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2016-08-29T20:00:43.020753Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2016-08-29T20:00:43.021754Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

wampmysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2016-08-29T20:01:02.323383Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2016-08-29T20:01:02.326385Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2016-08-29T20:01:02.328387Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2016-08-29T20:01:02.330389Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2016-08-29T20:01:02.331389Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

wampmysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2016-08-29T20:01:26.201624Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2016-08-29T20:01:26.203625Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2016-08-29T20:01:26.206627Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2016-08-29T20:01:26.208630Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2016-08-29T20:01:26.210631Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

What am I missing????

Comment: Looks like the old install is still in there running under services. try taking that out or try having your new install run on another port like 8080

Comment: Thanks VikingBlodded, can just help me how do I take it out?

Comment: I tried to run: sc delete wampmysqld64 in cmd. Said it was uninstalled succesfully. In services it is still showing with startup type: Disabled. I restarted WAMP, still Organe

Comment: Are you running WAMPServer as Administrator? It needs to be run as an administrator or it cannot access some files and it cannot start services

Comment: Yes I am RiggsFolly

Comment: Maybe I should try installing again now that I know how to disable the MySql service?

Comment: Refreshed the services list, the wamp service that I deleted was gone. Uninstalled wamp, refreshed the service list, wamp was not there. Reinstalled, Wamp still Orange.

Comment: Uninstalled and installed version 2.5. Now it works. Something is wrong with version 3

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by deleting (or renaming) the directory

```
C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.21\data
```

and then executing

```
./mysqld --initialize-insecure
```

from

```
C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.21\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

Install WAMP 2.5

Run the upgrade file from 2.5 to 3.

At last, it works

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are installing WAMP, please install it in a fresh folder.
For Visual C distributions, please download the following Visual C++ Redistributable Packages from [http://wampserver.aviatechno.net](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en):

Microsoft VC++ Packages x86 (32 bits)

- VC 2008 SP1 Package (x86) MD5
- VC 2008 SP1 ATL Package (x86) MD5
- VC 2008 SP1 MFC Package (x86) MD5
- VC 2010 SP1 Package (x86) MD5
- VC 2012 Update 4 (x86) MD5
- VC 2013 Package Up 5 (x86) MD5
- VC 2015-2019 (VC16 x86) 14.22.27821 MD5

As well as:

- VC 2008 SP1 Package (x64) MD5
- VC 2008 SP1 ATL Package (x64) MD5
- VC 2008 SP1 MFC Package (x64) MD5
- VC 2010 SP1 Package (x64) MD5
- VC 2012 Up 4 (x64) MD5
- VC 2013 Up 5 (x64) MD5
- VC 2015-2019 (VC16 x64) 14.22.27821 MD5

Alternate to this is download following:

Microsoft VC packages VC2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015-2019 zip files

- All VC Redistribuable Packages (x86) (32bits) MD5
- All VC Redistribuable Packages (x86_x64) (32 & 64bits) MD5